# Can one include filter dropdowns on a Show page in React-Admin?

Tags: material-ui, react-select, react-admin

E.g. Partly working code of what I want to achieve:

```
import {
  List,
  Show,
  Tab,
  AutocompleteArrayInput,
} from 'react-admin';

// react-select used as a convenient workaround, I found it more difficult to implement a 
//satisfactory alternative using MUI, which react-admin recommends for advanced filters.
import Select from 'react-select';


import SunburstZoomChart from '../charts/SunburstChart/SunburstZoomChart.jsx';


interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

export const EmployeeShow = () => {
  const handleMonthChange = (selectedOption: Option) => {
    setDaterange(selectedOption);
  };
  const handleAxesChange = (selectedOptions: Option[]) => {
    setAxes(selectedOptions);
  };
  const { record } = useShowController({ resource: 'employees' });
  const [daterange, setDaterange] = useState<Option>({
    label: 'June 2023',
    value: '[2023-06-01,2023-07-01)',
  });
  const [axes, setAxes] = useState<Option[]>([
    { label: 'Activity', value: 'activity' },
    { label: 'Project', value: 'project' },
    { label: 'Location', value: 'location' },
  ]);
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetList('rpc/timetracking_summary', {
    pagination: { page: 1, 1 },
    filter: {
      'axes@': `{user,daterange,${axes.map((option) => option.value).join(',')}}`,
      'date_part@': 'month',
      'zoom_level@': '2',
      user_id: record?.id,
      'daterange@cs': daterange.value,
    },
    meta: { columns: ['id', 'user_id', 'daterange', 'data'] },
  });
  return (
    <Show>
      <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Summary">
          ...
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Dashboard">
          <TextField source="username" />
          <Select
            value={daterange}
            onChange={handleMonthChange}
            options={[
              { label: 'June 2023', value: '[2023-06-01,2023-07-01)' },
              { label: 'May 2023', value: '[2023-05-01,2023-06-01)' },
              { label: 'April 2023', value: '[2023-04-01,2023-05-01)' },
            ]}
          />
          <Select
            value={axes}
            onChange={handleAxesChange}
            options={[
              { label: 'Activity', value: 'activity' },
              { label: 'Project', value: 'project' },
              { label: 'Location', value: 'location' },
            ]}
            isMulti
          />
          {!isLoading && (
            <SunburstZoomChart
              data={
                data?.length === 1
                  ? { name: 'Employee Timetracking Summary', children: data[0].data }
                  : { name: '', children: [] }
              }
            />
          )}
        </Tab>
      </TabbedShowLayout>
    </Show>
  );
};
```

The relevant docs are:

- [React-admin AutocompleteArrayInput](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AutocompleteArrayInput.html)
- [MUI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete)
- [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)

As an example, the following in place of <Select ... isMulti /> did not work (it gave a cryptic error of `methods is null`, while almost exactly the same works on the list view:

```
<AutocompleteArrayInput
  choices={[
    { id: 'activity', name: 'Activity' },
    { id: 'project', name: 'Project' },
    { id: 'aow', name: 'AoW' },
  ]}
  optionText="name"
  optionValue="id"
/>
```

Not sure how to interpret how to use onChange or how to set the dropdown's value by the documentation.

Although the dropdowns work, I like how they are off-screen unless requested as filters in the list view. Is there any way I can achieve this? Ideally I would also have conditional filters/dropdowns based on the axes chosen in the axes dropdown, so that users can optionally filter by the available axes.